# Prevenir envio de event do Google quando pressionado F5 e acesso via GET

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics-api

Fala pessoal!

Preciso fazer uma prevenção de envio de evento do analitycs no seguinte cenário:

Eu tenho um formulário que quando é dado o submit, o post é processado no ajax e esse ajax retorna uma URL na qual eu faço o redirecionamento via `location.href`. Essa outra página na qual recebe o direcionamento, tem o trecho de código onde envia o evento para o Google. O que acontece é que toda vez que o usuário da F5 ou entra no link diretamente, o evento está sendo contabilizado, dando resultados erroneos nos relatórios do Analitycs.

Segue um exemplo:

Página de Origem:

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="teste" />
  <button>Processar</button>
</form>
```

Página de destino:

```
<script>
 // preciso prevenir esse envio quando usuário der F5 ou entrar na página sem passar
 // pelo form
 ga('send', 'event', 'Teste', 'view', '<?php echo $_GET['varTeste'] ?>');
</script>
```

Script que faz o redirecionamento:

```
$( "#form" ).submit(function() {
  // ajax na qual retorna o link
  url = 'teste.php?varTeste=123';
  location.href = url;
});
```

Comment: Para que serve o $varTeste?

Comment: é um id para encontrar as informações desse id no banco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia adicionar o script ao DOM apenas se um parâmetro específico estiver presente no `$_GET`.

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['varTeste'])): ?>
    <script>...</script>
<?php endif ?>
```

E logo em seguida você pode remover esse parâmetro via JavaScript, assim quando a página fosse recarregada, ou acessada sem o parâmetro o script não iria ser adicionado ao DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // remove os parametros GET
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
});
```

Veja [replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method).

> Se necessário, adicione um  `setTimeout()` para atrasar a remoção do parâmetro da url.

Comment: Bom, vou usar uma variavel no banco para dizer se devo mandar o tracking ou não, mas mesmo assim obrigado!!